# Is there a way to implement context on async function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm writing a NodeJS based backend (cloud-function), and I got trouble in the situation as follow:

```js
const context = createContext()

async main(event){
  // I need to cache something here
  context.set("I need this")
  await someDeepFunction()
}

async function someDeepFunction() {
  // ...... and got it in a very-very-deep logic
  const val = context.get()
}
```

The main problem is that it's an async function, and when the NodeJS is handling the next request whiling waiting for the last, the context should switch automatically to ensure never lack the cache data of the first request.

I found a javascript project https://github.com/ealush/context, but it's not able to create context when use async.

Is it possible to implement and how?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/async_context.html (which is implemented using [async hooks](https://nodejs.org/api/async_hooks.html))

Comment: @jfriend00 Yep! I agree with you in most of situation. But my situation is to add something(user id, request id, etc.) to my log system to trace request between micro-services. It will be hard to provide these in every log :)

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for telling me that! It's so kind of you and I'm so glad to meet you! Wish you have a nice day XD